Is the expected value for this everywhere surjective function, w.r.t the Hausdorff measure in its dimension, defined and finite?
Suppose we want all Borel $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which answers this post. We denote each arbitrary Borel $f$ with $\mathcal{F}$.
My question is:

For any real $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}$ is the expected
value of $\left.f\right|_{[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]}$, w.r.t the
Hausdorff measure in its dimension, defined and finite?

If not, can we answer the question by defining a meaningful extension of the expected value on bounded $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e., we'll discuss the term "satisfying" after the leading question):

Leading Question: Can we define an unique, satisfying extension of the expected value, w.r.t the Hausdorff measure in its dimension, on bounded functions to $\mathcal{F}$, which takes finite values only, such that the set of all $\mathcal{F}$ with this extension forms:

A prevelant subset of $\mathbb{R}^{[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]}$
If 1. isn't possible, then a non-shy (i.e., neither prevelant nor shy) subset of $\mathbb{R}^{[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]}$?



Optional: In case the term "satisfying" is unclear, I attempted to define it in the following paper. (Note, this paper has unproven assumptions and isn't published. If it's too challenging, do not read.)

Edit: I added details to my research paper
Edit: I posted the second version with motivation, examples, and explanations.

How can you "define arbitrary Borel $f$ with $\cal F$" when you haven't defined $\cal F$? Did you perhaps mean "denote"? As in "denote the set of all Borel functions by $\cal F$"?

@PaulSinclair Yes, I meant “denote” but for each arbitrary Borel function, not the set of all Borel functions.

@PaulSinclair I don't know if you're still interested—I added details to my research paper
